# gwt google app engine HTTP ERROR 404

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I created a new gwt project with google application engine in eclipse.
But when I run the project, in the browser I got the following message.

> HTTP ERROR 404
>
> Problem accessing /Test.html. Reason:
>
> ```
> NOT_FOUND
> ```
>
> Powered by Jetty://

now it shows the following message.

> HTTP ERROR: 503
>
> Problem accessing /Test.html. Reason:
>
> ```
> SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
> ```
>
> Powered by Jetty://

What could be the problem? I did clean and build. But still the same problem.

Comment: Please post the contents of your Test.gwt.xml file. Also, do you have Test.html file in `web` directory?

Comment: actually when I created the project and run first time it worked fine. After that I shutdown the server and try to run it, I got the above messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you check that:

a) The correct project directory is selected as your WAR in your eclipse project GWT settings. You can check your project GWT settings by right-clicking on the project, selecting Properties, and then clicking on Google in the left-hand list (the Google item will have sub-items; the WAR should be specified in one of them).

b) The URL following the -startupUrl option in your run/debug configuration is correct if it exists (if it doesn't exist then you should add it).  The argument can be inserted into the "Program arguments" text field in the "Arguments" tab.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this problem, when my project facet had Java 1.8 version, GAE needs Java 1.7. 
You can change it by right clicking java and selecting "change version" here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use maven just write this line in cmd where your project is:

mvn clean package -DskipTests