# Google App Engine Hello World not working (Eclipxse, Java)

Tags: google-app-engine

I have checked and rechecked to see that I've done everything correctly, fixed a few problems with java 1.7 (set java compliance to 1.6) etc, and ran the program in develop mode and debug mode.

But when I go to the URL given (http://localhost:8888)  I get a 404 screen:

HTTP ERROR: 404

Problem accessing /. Reason:

```
NOT_FOUND
```

Powered by Jetty://

---

The welcome file index.html is in the war directory and web.xml lists index.html as the welcome file.  I get the same screen when I try to get the admin console at /_ah/admin as well.  The logs I could find didn't show anything.  Obviously GAE is working as it uses Jetty, any other port number I enter gives me a browser error:

Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:8887
Suggestions:
Try reloading: localhost:­8887
Search on Google:

---

So what could be the problem?  I checked file and directory permissions but I'm the only user on this computer ... any ideas or help is appreciated.

James

EDIT
I figured out the problem.  My browser cache was holding a different package I had installed previously in my workspace.  Simply clearing the cache after terminating all launches was the working solution.  I was then able to continue with the excellent tutorial.

http://googcloudlabs.appspot.com/whatgae.html

Answer (score 1):

GAE requires a controlled setup  and a good place to follow and start is GAE tutorial. Here is a link [GAE TUTORIAL](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/)

Answer (score 1):

Look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25205337/751641).

You have to change Java version in Project Facet also.

Answer (score 0):

GAE does not yet support being run with Java 1.7. Setting a compliance mode for Eclipse doesn't have any effect.

And that error you're getting form Eclipse for port :8887 is telling you that no application on your local machine is listening on that port. It provides no evidence one way or the other as to whether GAE is working.

Try again with Java 1.6.

Comment: Yes i had to install JRE 1.6 and then point eclipse to my installation directory.  Setting compliance mode to 1.6 (java compiler) DOES then work, contrary to your statement.