# Google Web Toolkit in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, google-apps-script

I've installed the **GWT plugin** in my **Eclipse Luna**. When I create a simple **Web Application Project** only for testing and using jre8, when running it and click on the link it shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJiGq.png) on browser, and if I change to jre7 it show [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAYCR.png).

I've also found out [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html) that *"GWT Development Mode will **no longer be available for Chrome** sometime in 2014, so we improved alternate ways of debugging. There are improvements to Super Dev Mode, asserts, console logging, and error messages."*

Can anyone tell me how to solve this errors if it is possible or what other ways of working with GWT are? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevMode works fine on the latest esr version of Firefox 24, but I use Eclipse 3.7 with jre7_25. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059544/how-to-install-gwt-browser-plugin) you can find a solution how to install GWT plugin in Chrome manually (regarding your 1st image).

On the 2nd image I see 404 error which means that the file is not there. Make sure the [war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644211/gwt-google-app-engine-http-error-404) path in your Run Configuration is correct (see Arguments tab). In my case I use -war  to specify a location to war directory.

P.S. [This](https://plus.google.com/wm/4/+BrianSlesinsky/posts/ZZ65wjQRnBB) information may be useful about DevMode.

Comment: Try not to link to other resources without at least giving a small summary of the relevant pieces from those sources.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different solutions you could take :

1. Downgrade to an older browser like [Firefox 24.8.1esr](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/24.8.1esr/) which still supports the GWT Developer Plugin.
2. Use the Super Devmode, which can be easily accessed in the GWT 2.7 version in Eclipse. More information about the Super Dev Mode can be found [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html).